# Using custom styles with Basic4Android

Tags: basic4android

As a follow on to the hide activity questions [here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-updates-questions/8635-hide-activity.html#post67780), I started looking through the Andoid documentation for more information on styles and themes and found it is possible to apply different themes for different API levels.

With this I can get my transparent activity on API levels that support it properly.

What I'd like to know is, is it safe to play with the styles within the Basic4Android environment, or will it comeback to bite me later on?

The xml has to be stored in res/values or res/values-v(API level) which are deleted on compile unless made read-only.  I just wanted to check if this was to stop these being changed for a reason, other than keeping the app tidy?.

Edit:
I assume some things that it is possible to put in these files would overwrite or be overwritten by settings in the Designer.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with using styles. Make sure to set your xml files to be read-only.
The designer doesn't change anything except of creating the bal files.

Comment: That's good news, thanks Erel.  It will go a long way towards being able to'Tabletize' apps.